# wget on Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, wget

Basically I'm trying to download images from a website using the following command (SwiftIRC is an easy example to use):

```
wget.exe -r -l1 -A.png --no-parent www.swiftirc.net/index.php
```

This command works fine, however one of the ways I am trying to do it isn't working.
When I fire up an elevated command prompt,  default to windows\system32.

If I use to following two commands everything works fine:

```
cd c:\users\tom\downloads\\

wget.exe -r -l1 etc. etc.**
```

The images are saved in the folder www.swiftirc.net in my downloads folder.
However if I try to do this in one line like this:

```
c:\users\tom\downloads\wget.exe -r -l1 etc. etc.
```

The response from wget on the cmd is exactly the same, but the images are not saved on my hard disk.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `c:\users\tom\downloads`\ to `PATH` or put `wget.exe` into your `windows/system32` folder.

Comment: Hi, I put wget.exe in the system32 folder and it worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I beleive it's because windows doesn't allow users to write files on the disk root, when you run "c:\users\tom\downloads\wget.exe" you have C:\ as a working directory so the files should be saved there but it's not allowed by the common strategies